# How to stay on selected tab after refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created tabs for my content instead of different HTML files, using anchor tags and fading them in and out with jQuery, but one problem I face is that if the user refreshes the page the home tab (initial tab) will be selected instead of the previously opened one.

I am currently using sessionStorage to store the previously opened tab like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Have the previously selected tab open
    if (sessionStorage.activeTab) {
        $('.tab-content ' + sessionStorage.activeTab).show().siblings().hide();
    //  ^ This one changes the tab to the previously opened, but after document has loaded :(
    }

// Enable, disable and switch tabs on click
$('.navbar .menu li a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    $('.tab-content ' + currentAttrValue).fadeIn(2000).siblings().hide();
    sessionStorage.activeTab = currentAttrValue;

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('.navbar .menu li a span').removeClass('active_span').removeClass('active_span2');
    $(this).children().addClass('active_span');
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

In the lower part of my code above, I have these lines which make white the icon and the word (eg. () Parentheses) belonging to the current tab white to show that they are active:

```
$(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
// ^ Icon

$(this).children().addClass('active_span');
// ^ Word
```

I tried to set them as items in sessionStorage too, as so:

```
sessionStorage.activeIcon = $(this).parent('li');
sessionStorage.activeWord = $(this).children();
```

but when I called them in the:

```
if (sessionStorage.activeTab) {}
```

it returned 'Null'. How can I save the icon and the word belonging to the previously opened tab and make them white as well as load all of them along with the tab before the document is loaded, so that no visible result of the changed is seen by the user?

It doesn't necessarily have to use sessionStorage. Any working answer or any answer that will put me on the right track is gladly accepted.

I am looking forward to reading your answers :)

P.S: I'm not using jQuery UI tabs or any other third party plugin.

**[EDIT]**

HTML (Tab-links):

```
<div class = "navbar tabs">
    <ul class = "menu tab-links">
        <li class = "active"><a class = "links" href = "#Dashboard"><span class = "focus active_span"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span class = "hider active_span">&nbsp;Dashboard</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a class = "links" href = "#Analytics"><span class = "focus"><i class = "fa fa-bar-chart fa-fw" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span class = "hider">&nbsp;Analytics</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a class = "links" href = "#Affiliate"><span class = "focus"><i class = "fa fa-user-plus fa-fw" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span class = "hider">&nbsp;Affiliate</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a class = "links" href = "#CashOut"><span class = "focus"><i class = "fa fa-money fa-fw" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span class = "hider">&nbsp;Cash Out</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a class = "links" href = "#Contest"><span class = "focus"><i class = "fa fa-trophy fa-fw" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span class = "hider">&nbsp;Contest</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a class = "links" href = "#Game"><span class = "focus"><i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-fw" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span class = "hider">&nbsp;Game</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a class = "links" href = "#FAQ"><span class = "focus"><i class = "fa fa-question-circle fa-fw" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span class = "hider">&nbsp;FAQ</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a class = "links" href = "#Settings"><span class = "focus"><i class = "fa fa-cog fa-fw" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span class = "hider">&nbsp;Settings</span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

HTML (Tab-content):

```
<div class = "tab-content">
    <div id = "Dashboard" class = "active tab"></div>
    <div id = "Analytics" class = "tab"></div>
    <div id = "Affiliate" class = "tab"></div>
    <div id = "FAQ" class = "tab"></div>
    <div id = "Settings" class = "tab"></div>
</div>
```

**[SOLVED]**

JavaScript:

To make the code work, we have to replace:

```
// Have the previously selected tab open
    if (sessionStorage.activeTab) {
        $('.tab-content ' + sessionStorage.activeTab).show().siblings().hide();
    //  ^ This one changes the tab to the previously opened, but after document has loaded :(
    }
```

with:

```
var activeTab = sessionStorage.activeTab;
$(".tab-content").fadeIn(1000);
if (activeTab) {
    $('.tab-content ' + activeTab ).show().siblings().hide();
    // also make sure you your active class to the corresponding tab menu here
    $(".menu li a[href=" + "\"" + activeTab + "\"" + "]").parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(".menu li a[href=" + "\"" + activeTab + "\"" + "]").children('span').addClass("active_span").parent().parent().siblings().children().children().removeClass('active_span');
    $(".menu li a[href=" + "\"" + activeTab + "\"" + "]").children('span').children().addClass("active_span").parent().parent().parent().siblings().children().children().children().removeClass('active_span');
}
else {
    activeTab = "#Dashboard";
    $('.tab-content ' + activeTab ).show().siblings().hide();
    // also make sure you your active class to the corresponding tab menu here
    $(".menu li a[href=" + "\"" + activeTab + "\"" + "]").parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(".menu li a[href=" + "\"" + activeTab + "\"" + "]").children('span').addClass("active_span").parent().parent().siblings().children().children().removeClass('active_span');
    $(".menu li a[href=" + "\"" + activeTab + "\"" + "]").children('span').children().addClass("active_span").parent().parent().parent().siblings().children().children().children().removeClass('active_span');
}
```

HTML:

In the HTML, we have to remove the classes 'active' and 'active_span' from the default **`<li>`** and **`<a>`** respectively.

```
<li class = "active"><a class = "links" href = "#Dashboard"><span class = "focus active_span"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span class = "hider active_span">&nbsp;Dashboard</span></span></a></li>
```

CSS:

Finally, in CSS we have to set the tab-content:

```
display: none;
```

Thanks to @KishoreBarik and @DavidChelliah for their tremendous help.

Comment: Store the `id` or `index` of the elements than storing the object/element itself

Comment: without your exact html all we can give you are ideas.

Comment: try `localStorage` in place of `sessionStorage`, as sessionStorage get's reset when you revisit the page

Comment: `localStorage`only store strings and use proper method to store new element `localStorage.setItem("new_item_name","value_of_the_item")`. 
after you can use `localStorage.getItem("new_item_name")`to use it.

Comment: @KishoreBarik localStorage has infinite duration. That means when they log in each time it will show them this page instead of the home page. What I want to achieve is if they are in a tab other than the homepage and they refresh show them this tab again, because it's annoying to be navigated back home.

Comment: The method I am using @Core972 is working. What I don't know is how to identify the icon and the word of the clicked so as to make them white and also how to make these things happen before document.ready so as not to produce any visible result of the change to the user.

Comment: @Jhecht what do you need the HTML for? The JS code is that I can't figure out. I'll edit the question and put an example.

Comment: Ok got it, If you have a login-logout mechanism, you can clear the local storage/ particular key on logout or assign them in anchors. So that when your tab is clicked you'll have `http:// path to your page#yourTab` in your address bar. Hence even if you reload you can get the active tab from url. If not found show the initial tab

Comment: its also good to use localStorage in javascript

Comment: @KishoreBarik when I click FAQfor instance, the url is http://blabla/index.php#FAQ. When I refresh, it stays the same but the Dashboard loads. If it helps, by default, I have the Dashboard -> display: inline-block and the rest -> display: none, so that only the Dashboard shows and then fade them in and out on click. Does this affect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using hash mechanism, 
inside your document ready function
replace your code

```
if (sessionStorage.activeTab) {
        $('.tab-content ' + sessionStorage.activeTab).show().siblings().hide();
```

with code to show the active tab as per hash like

```
var activeTab = window.location.hash;
if(activeTab.length){
  $('.tab-content ' + activeTab ).show().siblings().hide();
  // also make sure you set your active class to the corresponding tab menu here
}
```

Comment: Your code works in a way. I still don't know how to actually make the icon and the word white; how to get the specific ones that are needed. Also when I put a hash for the FAQ for example and navigate it shows me the Dashboard and when document is loaded then it changes to FAQ. How can I do it so that it goes there immediately or at least in away that the user can't see.

Comment: Keep **tab-content** div hidden by default initially(not whole body), show it when you set the active tab. I didn't get what you said about icon and word white thing. If it's about once you click the link the text color changes,  use  css **:visited** selector to set the color

Comment: Wow, keeping the tab-content hidden as default fixes the changing issue. With a little experimenting I kinda got the links to work too. Last thing, is to clear the sessionStorage on logout. Will sessionStorage.clear() do the trick?

Comment: I think now you don't need the sessionStorage for this task. The sessionStorage  get's cleared automatically on closing of the window. I was saying if you had used localStorage in place of sessionStorage then you could have achieved the same thing without playing with hash. In that case localStorage needed to be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the tab based solutions prefer hash value in the URL to deep link their content. The hash value from the URL will be set in URL,  like below

```
Www.xyz.com/test#tab1
```

tab1 is the ID of the tabbed content div and this also semantically reveals a correct meaning that, tab1 is a content internal document heading/link that should be in focus. Even if page reloads,  the browser will tend to automatically scroll down to that particular content section.

From the implementation point of view,
 On pageload just read through your tab anchor links and compare it against the hash value in the URL.  If it matches,  highlight the particular tab.  This kind of offloads the requirement from your part to persist the last clicked link.

```
  $(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var selectedTab = $('.navbar .menu li a [href= "'+hash+'"]');
    if(selectedTab.length){
         //Do your particular tab toggling
     }
});
```

Comment: Which part didn't work? I was using attribute selector  https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Straight from the console: Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function

Comment: I hope you have include jquery. Few edits in my code

Comment: There are no errors now, but it doesn't work. It does nothing. When I refresh it goes back to Dashboard being the active tab. Even when I type for instance #FAQ at the end of the url it still shows the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage should be used with `.setItem()` and `.getItem()` function.

Storage can only store data in string form, so when you need store object, you should use `JSON.stringify()` to change it to string, and `JSON.parse()` before you use it. So you can store the activeTab, word and icon in one object.

I suggest you store the icon by its class, jQuery object can't be used after JSON stringify and parse. The same with word.

There is no need to change the tab before document.ready, just add `display: none;` to body, and make it visible after you change the tab.

Comment: Nice to learn about the two JSON methods, but as regard setting display: none to the body I think that's a bad idea. Will the page is loading the user will be seeing a white emptiness and then out of nowhere comes the body at an instant. It will look like a hitch...

Comment: In this case, you need a back-end template system, it will return the correctly rendered html to user, this is the ideal way. imo, modifying page by js when page is loaded is not a good idea in most case.@AngelPolitis